# IIS 7.0 looking in wrong Physical Path

Tags: wcf, iis-7, appfabric

I'm having problems accessing a deployed WCF service.

I created the Virtual Directory for the service, configured AppFabric and everything went well until I tried to access it. AppFabric sees the Service and IIS seems to be happy with it but it complains in the browser that the resource has been removed and when I check the Physical Path it's looking in another one.

My Physical path is C:\Sites\Services and it's looking in C:\Sites\Websites.

I checked the Physical Path of the default website and it's %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot

Now I can't seem to find where the problem is, the physical path seems correct.